# How to find how many Ethernet cards are in my computer?

Tags: python

I want to write code to find how many Ethernet cards my computer has. Any ideas?

Comment: When the question is about specific components you shall specify the OS for better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no protable way to do so unless you have any specific OS in mind.

- As for Win32/Win64 you can parse the o/p from ipconfig /all
- As for linux you can parse the o/p from lshw -class network
- As for other systems similar things should be here

You can extend the below code, by adding more system, commands and parse string

```
>>> netCmds={'Windows': [['ipconfig', '/all'], 'Description',':'], 'Linux': [['lshw', '-class', 'network'], 'product',':']}
>>> netcmd=netCmds[platform.system()]
>>> for l in subprocess.check_output(netcmd[0]).splitlines():
        if netcmd[1] in l:
            print l.split(netcmd[2])[-1]
```

If you need to support more systems just append netCmds list as follows

`<System_name>:[[<command to list n/w info>....],<parse_string>,<Split character>]`

Please note System_info should conform with what you would get with platform.system() in the target OS.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's my shot at this (for some reason, I suppose OP has windows OS. )

```
import win32com.client
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
print len(filter(lambda obj : obj.Caption.lower().find('ethernet') > -1, colItems))
```

you can download the imported win32 module here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build216/

Note, that I've counted those adapters, where the Caption attribute contains the word 'ethernet'. Probably you'll want to use some more clever criteria.

Source: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0acad814-7e8f-4924-af85-58b5bd6eb826

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can read the `/proc/net/dev` file or use `system()` to execute `ifconfig -s`, see proc [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for details. Alternatively, you can use [`fcntl.ioctl()`](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html) with *SIOCGIFCONF*. On other UNIX-like systems `ifconfig` and `fcntl.ioctl()` should work, too.

Comment: I would use subprocess instead of system(). [Python docs for os.system()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) mention this as well.

Comment: Valid point. Thanks for the link.